# docker set iptables options in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker

I'm using docker-compose for managing containers.

How to I turn off iptables (set --iptables=false for docker) when starting via docker-compose up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `--iptables` option only applies to the Docker daemon; it's not a per-container option.  The corollary is that this isn't something you could ever set from your `docker-compose.yaml` file.

You would need to modify the options passed to the Docker daemon; on Red Hat systems and derivatives this means you would modify `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and updte the `OPTIONS=` line (and restart Docker).  There will be a similar process for other distributions.

Comment: On Ubuntu/Debian systems, you edit `/etc/default/docker` so that docker_opts is uncommented and contains the iptables addition: `docker_opts="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --iptables=false"` ([source](https://forums.docker.com/t/running-multiple-docker-containers-with-ufw-and-iptables-false/8953/8))

Comment: It's also worth noting (and probably worth adding a note in your answer) that by enabling this setting after previously running docker w/ some network configuration will cause the related iptables rules to remain enabled -- at least in my experience. So if someone is trying to use this `--iptables=false` setting so that they can manually control their own firewall (e.g., UFW), then they should clear the iptable rules appropriately after enabling this docker setting (and restarting docker/server).

Answer (score 0):

Could check out saltstack if you're looking for this level of automation. They have a dockerng state which allows you to specify options.

https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.dockerng.html